# How can I append list items from input with effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, effects, listitem

I am writing a code that is supposed to make a shopping list based on input. So I have an input field and button that adds the item to the list. And also the item should disappear when it's clicked. I managed to make it work like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $("ul").append("<li>" + $("#input_field_value").val());
  });
  $("ul").on("click", "li", function(e){
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

However, I need to make the new list items to append and remove with an effect and I can't make it work. I learned that you can't just add effects to append -command. I managed to get my code to add new list items with an effect BUT it won't print the value of the input field to the new list item. The new list item is empty. And also the whole unordered list shows again with an effect when a new item is added, only the new item should appear with an effect. Also, the removing items with a click doesn't work anymore. This is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    var inputvalue = $("#input_field_value").val();
    var item = $("<li>" + inputvalue);
    $("ul").append(item).hide().fadeIn(1000);
  });
  $("ul").on("click", "li", function(e){
    $(this).remove().hide().fadeOut(1000);
  });
});
```

I tried some other stuff as well, like messing around with appenTo but couldn't get it to work.

This is probably pretty obvious for a more experienced coder but I just can't figure this one out :)

Thank's for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You're hiding/removing before applying the effect `fadeOut()`.
- You're adding before applying the effect `fadeIn()`.
- Use the callback of `fadeOut` to remove the element just before the effect ends.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var inputvalue = $("#input_field_value").val();
    var item = $("<li>" + inputvalue + '</li>');
    item.hide();
    $("ul").append(item);
    item.fadeIn(1000);
  });
  $("ul").on("click", "li", function(e) {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='input_field_value'>
<p/>
<button id='button'>Click me!</button>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Big thank's! Now I got it to work and even better, I realized what I was doing wrong. It all makes sense now.